# How is a delegate executed

Tags: c#, delegates

I'm working with some code that I've found online and I don't quite understand delegates yet. I read some articles about it but the examples I've seen are much more simplistic and not very similar. This is the code I'm having trouble with:

```
var cb = new Action<OAuthAccessToken, TwitterResponse>(CallBackVerifiedResponse);
service.GetAccessToken(_requestToken, pinText.Text, CallBackVerifiedResponse);
```

Is the `new Action` object actually executing the `CallBackVerifiedResponse` method or does that only happen in the second line? `OAuthAccessToken` and `TwitterResponse` are the types of the parameters that the `CallBackVerifiedResponse` method asks for but to me it doesn't look like they're initialized at any point.

Can someone offer me an explanation or an alternative/more simpel way to write those two lines? Here's the full method just in case:

```
    void CallBackVerifiedResponse(OAuthAccessToken at, TwitterResponse response)
    {
        if (at != null)
        {
            SerializeHelper.SaveSetting<TwitterAccess>("TwitterAccess", new TwitterAccess
            {
                AccessToken = at.Token,
                AccessTokenSecret = at.TokenSecret,
                ScreenName = at.ScreenName,
                UserId = at.UserId.ToString()
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither. The code inside `GetAccessToken` will call the `CallBackVerifiedResponse` method at some point. Or not. Depends on the code in `GetAccessToken`. I asssume it'll call it when the response has been verified.

Basically, a delegate is a way to hand someone a function and say "Make this function call later, when you need it".

`OAuthAccessToken` and `TwitterResponse` are initialized within `GetAccessToken`. That's the goal of `GetAccessToken` - to asynchronously get you an `OAuthAccessToken` and tell you about it when it's done. The purpose of the delegate is to provide the API with a mechanism to do that.

Comment: But what happens with the `CallBackVerifiedResponse` in the first line than? `var cb` is not used anywhere else and `Action` isn't defined by me

Comment: Good question! Action<T,T> is a way to say that this is an instance of a delegate that takes two parameters and returns nothing. Action<OAuthAccessToken, TwitterResponse> is the defined type version. You can't pass just any function into GetAccessToken - it wouldn't know what to do with int foo(File f), for example. In the bad old days, you would have had to do a lot of busy work to define the right set of parameters.

Comment: Basically, it's the box that you're putting your function in, and it's shaped in such a way that only the right kind of function can get passed.

Comment: But it isn't used though in this case, is it? `cb` isn't called anywhere.. or is that not necessary? Thanks for your help!

Comment: cb's used inside GetAccessToken to make that call to CallBackVerifiedResponse. Somewhere in that code there's something that looks like this (variable names are obviously wrong): cb(myauthtoken, mytwitterresponse); and that statement will cause your CallBackVerifiedResponse function to fire.

Comment: But cb is not passed to the GetAccessToken at any point and it's a local variable. GetAccessToken is not even a function written by me, it's part of the TweetSharp library so how does it know about cb?

Comment: Sorry for asking this many questions I'm having a hard time grasping this. I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

Neither the first nor the second line execute the `CallBackVerifiedResponse` method. In both cases, a method pointer of that method is passed to a method (in the first line, to the `Action` constructor, and in the second line, to `GetAccessToken`.

The method may be invoked later on by some code in `CallBackVerifierResponse`.

Answer (score 1):

A simple example

```
DoWork(CallThisWhenFinished);


public void DoWork(Action action) //<--GetAccessToken
{
    MessageBox.Show("DoWork");
    action();
}

public void CallThisWhenFinished() //<--CallBackVerifiedResponse
{
    MessageBox.Show("CallMeWhenFinished");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can think of a delegate as a reference to a method.

In the code:

```
service.GetAccessToken(_requestToken, pinText.Text, CallBackVerifiedResponse);
```

the `CallBackVerifiedResponse` method is not actually executed. If there were parenthesis after it:

`CallBackVerifiedResponse()` then the method would be executed, but without the parenthesis, it is going to pass a reference to the method into `service.GetAccessToken()` so that that method can execute the method itself.

Comment: But what happens with the `CallBackVerifiedResponse` in the first line than? `var cb` is not used anywhere else and `Action` isn't defined by me

Comment: in your 2 lines of code, the line `var cb = new Action<OAuthAccessToken, TwitterResponse>(CallBackVerifiedResponse);` does nothing. All it does is to wrap a reference to the `CallBackVerifiedResponse` method into an `Action` instance, but the method won't be called unless there is some later code to make a call to (execute the action) `cb`. Maybe your 2nd line of code was supposed to be `service.GetAccessToken(_requestToken, pinText.Text, cb);` which I think (depending on that GetAccessToken method) would function exactly the same.